# Pico W Webserver not responding

Tags: micropython, pi-pico-w

I'm playing with setting up a Raspberry Pi Pico Web Server I can get it to connect to my router and the IP address it gives me shows up if I do "arp -a" however if I try to connect with a browser or ping it all I see are timeouts.

Here's my Web Server Python Code (Straight out of the tutorial)

```
import machine
import time
import socket
import network

# set led pin
led = object;
PICO_W = False
try:
    led = machine.Pin("LED", machine.Pin.OUT)
    PICO_W=True
except:
    led = machine.Pin(25, machine.Pin.OUT)

led.value(0)

ssid = 'MyRouterSSID'          #Enter the router name
password = 'MyPassword'      #Enter the router password

wifi_status = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
wifi_status.disconnect()
wifi_status.active(True)
wifi_status.connect(ssid, password)

def WebPage():
    if led.value() == 1:
        gpio_state = 'On'
    else:
        gpio_state = 'OFF'
    
    # html code ...
    html = """
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Pico W Web Server</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="icon" href="data:,">
            <style>
                html{font-family: Helvetica; display:inline-block; margin: 0px auto; text-align: center;}
                h1{color: #0F3376; padding: 2vh;}
                p{font-size: 1.5rem;}
                button{display: inline-block; background-color: #4286f4; border: none;border-radius: 4px; color: white; padding: 16px 40px; text-decoration: none; font-size: 30px; margin: 2px; cursor: pointer;}
                button2{background-color: #4286f4;}
            </style>
        </head>
        <body> <h1>Pico W Web Server</h1> 
          <p>GPIO state: <strong>""" + gpio_state + """</strong></p>
          <p><a href="/?led=on"><button class="button">ON</button></a></p>
          <p><a href="/?led=off"><button class="button button2">OFF</button></a></p>
        </body>
    </html>
    """
    return html
t=0
# check wifi connected
while wifi_status.isconnected() == False:
    time.sleep(1)
    t+=1
    print('Connect to a wireless network...',t)
    led.value(t % 2)

led.value(1)
    
# if connected
print('Wifi connect successful')
print(ssid.strip(),wifi_status.ifconfig())


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('', 80))
s.listen(5)
try:
    while True:
        print("Waiting")
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print('Connection: %s' % str(addr))
        req = conn.recv(1024)
        req = str(req)
        print('Connect = %s' % req)
        led_on = req.find('/?led=on')
        led_off = req.find('/?led=off')
        if led_on == 6:
            print('LED ON')
            led.value(1)
        else:
            print('LED OFF')
            led.value(0)
        if led.value() == 1:
            gpio_state = 'On'
        else:
            gpio_state = 'OFF'
        response = WebPage()
        conn.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n')
        conn.send('Content-Type: text/html\n')
        conn.send('Connection: close\n\n')
        conn.sendall(response)
        conn.close()
except:
    conn.close()
    s.close()
    print("Closed")
    pass
```

And here's the console output

```
MPY: soft reboot
Connect to a wireless network... 1
Connect to a wireless network... 2
Connect to a wireless network... 3
Wifi connect successful
MyNetworkSSID ('192.168.0.29', '255.255.255.0', '192.168.0.1', '194.168.4.100')
Waiting
```

If I ping 192.168.0.29 or connect in a browser to 192.168.0.29 it just times out with no further output in the console.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `Any thoughts?` is not a question about the web server ... please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: I'd suggest you work on this a bit more; read and re-read. Surely there are good examples online for doing this?

Comment: @Seamus thanks I've tried several other examples this is a slightly modified version of the Freenove example that came with the Pico (All my mods do is tell it to use the onboard LED and make that flash whilst its connecting) I'm beginning to think that either the Pico is faulty or the onboard led is interfering with the WIFI which is possible

Comment: don't modify the example code before confirming that it works ... look for "Hello World" example code